# Enlarge animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to achieve the below animation in android I have tried scenes but scenes do not work with text as per docs it is confirmed :

"If you try to resize a TextView with an animation, the text will pop to a new location before the object has completely resized. To avoid this problem, do not animate the resizing of views that contain text."

Please any solution , the enlarged layout text can contain images too.
[animation video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pupaE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

this thing worked some how ,but the animation is little jittery,I guess layout height final value is attained first and layoutWidth later, have to fix this.    this is my enlarge/reduce animation :

```
public class EnlargeAnimation extends Animation {

private final int diffHeight;
private final int diffWidth;
private final int initialHeight;
private final int initialWidth;
private final View targetView;

public EnlargeAnimation(View targetView, float targetHeight, float targetWidth) {
    this.targetView = targetView;
    this.initialHeight = targetView.getMeasuredHeight();
    this.initialWidth = targetView.getMeasuredWidth();
    this.diffHeight = (int) (targetHeight-initialHeight);
    this.diffWidth = (int) (targetWidth-initialWidth);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

    float newHeight = initialHeight + diffHeight * interpolatedTime;
    float newWidth = initialWidth + diffWidth * interpolatedTime;
    targetView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) newHeight;
    targetView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) newWidth;
    targetView.requestLayout();
}
```

}

this is when enlarge animation is called :

I am using viewpager so i have to make padding negative to enlarge the card size :

```
  ValueAnimator paddingAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(20, -10).setDuration(400);
                paddingAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                paddingAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                        int padding = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                        view.setPadding(padding,
                                (int) DeviceUtils.convertDpToPx(50, v.getContext()), padding,
                                (int) DeviceUtils.convertDpToPx(50, v.getContext()));
                        view.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
                viewPagerItemSizeListener.onEnlarged();
                EnlargeAnimation
                        enlargeAnimation =
                        new EnlargeAnimation(cardView, screenHeight, screenWidth);
                enlargeAnimation.setDuration(400);
                enlargeAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        paddingAnimator.start();
                        seeExampleText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        stage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        cardEnlargedWidth = cardView.getLayoutParams().width;
                        cardEnlargedHeight = cardView.getLayoutParams().height;
                        crossContianer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        detailTextContianer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
                view.startAnimation(enlargeAnimation);
```

I guess no one is reading it, but if something is confusing about variables let me know i will edit the answer.